# SQLSTATE[01004] error

Tags: mysql, pdo

I have this bit of code:

```
<?php 
$dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbase;charset=utf8';
$username = 'dbaseu';
$password = '123456f';

$db = new PDO($dsn,  $username, $password, array(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false, PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));

foreach($db->query('SELECT DISTINCT
oc_product.product_id AS unu,
GROUP_CONCAT(oc_category_description.name) AS doi,
oc_product.model AS trei,
oc_product.image AS patru,
oc_product.price AS cinci,
oc_product_description.name AS sase,
oc_product_description.description AS sapte,
GROUP_CONCAT(oc_product_image.image) AS opt
FROM
oc_product INNER JOIN oc_product_description ON oc_product.product_id = oc_product_description.product_id
INNER JOIN oc_product_image ON oc_product_description.product_id = oc_product_image.product_id
INNER JOIN oc_product_to_category ON oc_product_image.product_id = oc_product_to_category.product_id
INNER JOIN oc_category_description ON oc_product_to_category.category_id = oc_category_description.category_id
GROUP BY unu') as $row) //*** THIS IS LINE 44 ***
?>

<table id="mytable">
<thead><tr><th>ID</th><th>Category</th><th>Name</th><th>Poze</th></tr></thead>
<tbody>
<?php 
{
echo '<tr>';
echo '<td>'.$row['unu'].'</td><td>'.intoarce_unice($row['doi']).'</td><td>'.$row['sase'].'</td><td>'.intoarce_unice($row['opt']).'</td>';
echo '</tr>';
}
?>
```

And an error

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[01004]: String data, right truncated' in /var/.../htdocs/oc/flish/filter.php:44 Stack trace: #0 /var/.../htdocs/oc/flish/filter.php(44): unknown() #1 {main} thrown in /var/.../htdocs/oc/flish/filter.php on line 44

What exactly is the issue here? 
The code works, but for the moment I only have about 20 records, so it's easy to check. 
The same code did NOT raise an error on a standard XAMPP installation on linux.

Comment: I would _guess_ that the content of one of the `GROUP_CONCAT()` statements is _longer_ then [`group_concat_max_len`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en///server-system-variables.html#sysvar_group_concat_max_len), but normally those would be warnings AFAIK.... You could increase that value & see what happens./

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked, although the DB admin increased pretty much everything so I cannot be sure what exactly needed more resources. But it was definitely an issue of increasing the available resources.